# Using usort results in an error when trying to sort array of objects

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, object, usort

Please explain why I receive this error when trying to sort array of objects:
`usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Screenshot of array: http://prntscr.com/ik3ira
Screenshot of error: http://prntscr.com/ik3dte

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp(count($a->bank->credits), count($b->bank->credits));
}
$banks=usort($banks, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a collection, not an array of objects. I am going to assume you use Laravel, in which case the collection already provides a sortBy function that you can use.

If your objects contain a bank object that contains a credits attribute, it would look like this:

```
$banks = $banks->sortBy(function ($bank, $key) {
    return $bank->bank->credits;
});
```

That would be the cleaner way.

You could alternatively convert it via toArray to an array of objects (which you expected to begin with) and then proceed to be using your code.

Comment: Good! Indeed it was Laravel magic!

Answer (score 1):

[usort](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_usort.asp) accepts an array as its first parameter, But you are passing an object

**also pass a callback as second parameter please**

use `toArray` function

```
$banks=usort($banks->toArray(), $callBackFucntion);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message, `$banks` is not an array but an object..

Unfortunately,`usort` works only with arrays. If you want you can typecast `$banks` to an associtive array, so your `usort` call could look like this maybe :

`$banks = usort(array($banks), "cmp");`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @It is all yours answer is a better one, forgot we're dealing with Laravel